# secure my Nfc tag by sending password on it

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am doing an application that can read nfc and then treat the content message but I only want certain people to be able to read the tag. So in a way I would like the user to scan the tag and be prompted for a password before being able to read the tag. Is this possible ?
Open to any ideas. It is also possible to keep only the read mode and change the write mode to kind of writing password on the tag to secure it.

```
btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        if(myTag ==null) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, ERROR_DETECTED, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            write(message.getText().toString(), myTag);
                            Toast.makeText(context, WRITE_SUCCESS, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, WRITE_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (FormatException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, WRITE_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
            if (nfcAdapter == null) {
                // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
                Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            readFromIntent(getIntent());

            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
            IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
            tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };
        }

        private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                    || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                    || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
                NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
                if (rawMsgs != null) {
                    msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                        msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                    }
                }
                buildTagViews(msgs);
            }
        }
        private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
            if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

            String text = "";
//        String tagId = new String(msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getType());
            byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
            String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16"; // Get the Text Encoding
            int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063; // Get the Language Code, e.g. "en"
            // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");

            try {
                // Get the Text
                text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString());
            }
            tvNFCContent.setText(text+"\n( taille de la trame: " + text.length () +")");
        }
        private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {
            NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
            NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
            // Get an instance of Ndef for the tag.
            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            // Enable I/O
            ndef.connect();
            // Write the message
            ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
            // Close the connection
            ndef.close();
        }
        private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            String lang       = "en";
            byte[] textBytes  = text.getBytes();
            byte[] langBytes  = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
            int    langLength = langBytes.length;
            int    textLength = textBytes.length;
            byte[] payload    = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

            // set status byte (see NDEF spec for actual bits)
            payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

            // copy langbytes and textbytes into payload
            System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1,              langLength);
            System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, textLength);

            NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,  NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,  new byte[0], payload);

            return recordNFC;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            setIntent(intent);
            readFromIntent(intent);
            if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
                myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            WriteModeOff();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            WriteModeOn();
        }

        private void WriteModeOn(){
            writeMode = true;
            nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
        }
        private void WriteModeOff(){
            writeMode = false;
            nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have the password implementation **either** in the readFromIntent replacing the `buildTagViews(msgs);` with `checkPasswordDialog(msgs)`

```
private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
.....
.... checkPasswordDialog(msgs)  
...
```

In the checkPasswordDialog(NdefMessage[] msgs), you check the password, if it is correct,then continue with `buildTagViews(msgs);` else, show error.

**Or** in the `buildTagViews(msgs);` itself, right before you display the message, the password then determines what you will display, the NFC message or an error( non-authorized user).

Assume I write a function called checkForPasswordDailog() thats asks a user for a password. If the password entered by user is correct then continue to display the messege otherwise display and unauthorised user messege. i.e

```java
    protected void checkForPasswordDialog(NdefMessage[] msgs){
        /*create a dialog view with either both usename 
         and password or just a password if every user uses the same 
         password*/
   
         MaterialDialog(this).show{
             // add a title
             View passwordDialogView = customView(R.layout.password_dialog_view)
             //when the user submits their inputs
             Textview userNameView = passwordDialogView.findViewById(R.id.username)
             Textview passwordView = passwordDialogView.findViewById(R.id.password)
             Button submitButton = passwordDialogView.findViewById(R.id.submit_button) 
             
             submitButton.setOnClickListener{
                 if(verifyUser(username.text, password.text)){
                     buildTagViews(msgs)
                     cancel()
                 }else{
                     showUnauthorizedUserError()
                     cancel()
                } 
         }

         
   }

   protected boolean verifyUser(String username, String password){
       //Verify user input 
   }

   protected void showUnauthorizedUseError(){
       //Display your message here Snackbar/Dialog e.t.c
   }
```

And your xml file should include

```xml
    <TextView id = "@+id/username"/>
    <TextView id = "@+id/password"/>
    <Button id = "@+id/submit_button"/>
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to do it?

Comment: I have edited the code to include the said function, I hope that is helpful, so you will replace the buildTagViews(msgs); with the checkForPasswordDialog(msgs) and build a dialog view in that function, if the user enters the correct password, continue to display the message, otherwise alert the user that their credentials are invalid. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: How the password could be change or it will be always the same, I tried to do some but it doesnt word, is there need to also add someting to xml code? can you give the complete code please with complete checkForPasswordDailog.

Comment: I usually use this library for my dialogs https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs but basically I would suggest you write an xml file which will ask for password and or username depending on what you will need and of course a button for submission. I will edit the code with the assumption that the xml exists.

Comment: This is kotlin and I use Java, if I put void in place of fun and change val by java's value, it will be ok?

Comment: My bad, I rarely use java nowadays but I hope that clarifies it, just be sure to implement the MaterialDialog properly though and let me know how it goes. Otherwise we can move this into a chat.